# Impulse mechanics issue

Tags: linear-algebra

I dont see what I have done wrong with my arithmetic to get two different answers two different ways for this mechanics question?

I used $I=mv-mu$ but get 6.5ms for one answer and 3.5ms for the other?

Please help.[image: My workings]
Sorry about my handwriting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the right, when you moved the term $mu$ to the left-hand side of the equation, you put the wrong sign:

$I=mv-mu$ should give $I+mu=mv$.